# Beginner's C++ program for a class

Tags: c++

the assignment is the basic "cin a full name" and then "retrieve First Middle Last" bit, where you create a program that asks the user to type in their full first name into a single string and the programs picks apart the name and outputs it organized seperately. this is what i wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int index;
    index = name.find(' ');
    cin >> name;
    cout << "First name: " << name.substr(0, index) << endl;
    name = name.substr(index+1, name.length()-1);
    index = name.find(' ');
    cout << "Middle Name: " << name.substr(1, index) << endl;
    name = name.substr(index+1, name.length()-1);
    cout << "Last name: " << name;
    return 0;
}
```

the code just wont seperate them right, and will not redefine 'name' correctly.
It always just bounces back to the beginning of the string.
any help for a newbie?
here's an example output:

```
Teenage Wonder Land
First name: Teenage
Middle Name: eenag
Last name: Teena
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 7.942 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Try printing `name` and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: don't quite understand, i typed in name into the program and got the same results; the program cannot seperate the names besides the first name.

Comment: I just reverted your edit, because it changed the entire question. Doing so after you've received answers based on your original code is inappropriate; it makes the answers you've received totally invalid, and makes the people posting those answers look foolish. We can't hit a moving target.

Comment: i apologize, should i just repost the new code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `std::getline` to get the entire line of text at once. Currently you are only reading in the first word (`>>` operator will only extract text up to the next whitespace character).

```
std::string name;
if (std::getline(cin, name))
{
    // extraction successful, "name" should contain entire line
}
```

Then, you can use one of the other answers in this question or continue with your own approach.

Comment: @dreamlax: Downvoted because you didn't actually answer the question. Your answer should be a comment under the question itself.

Comment: @moonman239: It's too hard to display code in a comment. I already attributed the other answers as well. It should be a comment, but StackOverflows comment system isn't perfect, and sometimes you need more space than a comment in order for the point to be clear.

Answer (score 2):

You wont' find anything before type your in console and `sbustr` should read from index `0`

```
string name;
int index;
//index = name.find(' '); // comment out, name is empty, you won't find anything

cin >> name;
index = name.find(' '); // now you can find first space

cout << "Middle Name: " << name.substr(0, index) << endl;
//                                     ^
```

Or just use `std::stringstream`

```
  #include <sstream>

  std::stringstream ss(name);
  std::string token;
  int i = 0;
  while(ss >> token)
  {
    switch(i)
    {
      case 0: 
        std::cout << "First name: " << token << std::endl;
        break;
      case 1: 
        std::cout << "Middle name: " << token << std::endl; 
        break;
      case 2: 
        std::cout << "Last name: " << token << std::endl; 
        break;
      default:
        break;
      i++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried both corrections, however its still only seperating out the first name, and the redefinition of name after "First Name :" line isn't only selecting past the first space

Comment: @user2778369

Declare a `string` variable `name` and add `std::getline(std::cin, name);` to the code. Do all this before the line `std::stringstream ss(name);`. Then try again

Answer (score 1):

You clearly can't search for something in `name` before you assign it a value, which is what you're doing now:

```
string name;
int index;

index = name.find(' ');  // No value assigned to name yet - nothing to search
cin >> name;             // Now you're giving it a value (too late)
```

Instead, assign and *then* try to find a value:

```
string name;
int index;

cin >> name;            // Assign a value first
index = name.find(' '); // Now try to find something in it
```

Comment: I have editted my original post with the corrections i have made thus far, but am still running into the same problem unfortunately, so i am not sure if that is the problem, although that definitely could have caused it and i am now running into a new problem with the same results.

Comment: @user2778369: I just removed your edit (see my comment above for the reason why). "I'm still running into the same problem" is nonsense, because the change I showed you fixes that problem. "I'm now running into a new problem" with no information about what it is is also meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The extraction operator `>>` for istream will grab all non-whitespace characters in the buffer until it encounters a whispace.

So your input here:

```
Teenage Wonder Land
```

contains 3 whitespaces including the invisible newline at the end when you hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. From this you should be able to figure out what the following does:

```
cin >> name;
```

Hint: `name` doesn't contain the entire line you just entered.

Comment: This is my problem right here. So what operator should i use to fix that? is there a string Get dot function i can use to get the whole line into name? White spaces and all?

Comment: @user2778369 you can call `cin >> name` three times or you can use `getline(cin, name);` to get the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string getnext(const string &full, const string &delim, size_t &beg) {
    size_t prev = beg;
    beg = full.find(delim, beg);
    if (beg != string::npos)
        return full.substr(prev, beg-prev);
    return full.substr(prev, full.length()-prev);
}

int main()
{
    string name, temp, error = "NameError: Enter first, middle, last";
    size_t index = 0;
    getline(cin, name); //Get the full name

    temp = getnext(name, " ", index); //Get first name
    if (index == string::npos) {
        cout << error;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "First name: " << temp << endl;

    temp = getnext(name, " ", ++index); //Get middle name
    if (index == string::npos) {
        cout << error;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Middle Name: " << temp << endl;

    temp = getnext(name, " ", ++index); //Get last name
    cout << "Last name: " << temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```